# この商品は人気があるから、十日ぐらいで売り切れるはずだ

Tags: meaning

この商品は人気があるから、十日ぐらいで売り切れるはずだ

Can someone explain what the で in this sentence means?
As far as I know で has these 3 meanings:
1 - (連用形) of the assertive auxiliary (断定の助動詞), or "copula", だ/です
2 - 主体を表す。This で is used to indicate the agent of the action.
3 - で as marking "how". It specifies how something happens.

Comment: This 10日くらいで means "**in** about 10 days".

Comment: @naruto Thanks , there was another similar question so I will delete this one